# why doesn't the window open?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML code, the problem is in the Check function. I want the alert to pop up when I don't enter a number or enter a number bigger than 10 and smaller than 0.
Instead it calculates the average when I give it a letter and gives me NaN which I don't want. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Grade</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
function trimfield(str) 
{ 
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); 
}
function Check()
{
 var counter=0;
 var lesson = new Array();
 lesson[0] = window.prompt("1st Lesson Grade", "0");
 lesson[1] = window.prompt("2nd Lesson Grade", "0");
 lesson[2] = window.prompt("3rd Lesson Grade", "0");
 lesson[3] = window.prompt("4th Lesson Grade", "0");
 lesson[4] = window.prompt("5th Lesson Grade", "0");
 lesson[5] = window.prompt("6th Lesson Grade", "0");
 x = parseFloat(lesson[0]);
 x1 = parseFloat(lesson[1]);
 x2 = parseFloat(lesson[2]);
 x3 = parseFloat(lesson[3]);
 x4 = parseFloat(lesson[4]);
 x5 = parseFloat(lesson[5]);
 avrg = (x + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)/6;
 var reg = document.getElementById('srn').value;
 var name = document.getElementById('fn').value;
 var lastname = document.getElementById('ln').value;
 var i;
 var hasError = false;
 var myWindow = window.open("", "Grade", "width=500,height=500");
 myWindow.document.write("<h3>The average is: " + avrg  + "<br>" + "First Name: " + name + "<br>"+ "Last Name: " + lastname  + "<br>"+ "Studen Registration Number: " + reg + "</h3>");
 
 for(i=0; i<6;i++){
  if(!isNaN(lesson[i].value)){
   hasError = true;
   counter=1;
  }
  else if(trimfield(lesson[i].value) == '') {      
   hasError = true;
            lesson[i].focus(); 
   counter=1;
        }
  else if(lesson[i].value<0 || lesson[i].value>10){
   hasError = true;
   counter=1;
  } else
   counter=0;
  }
  
  if(counter==1){
   alert("Wrong Info")
  }  
    return !hasError;
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#ffffcc">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Personal Info:</legend>
  <form>
   <label for="fn">First Name:</label>
   <input id="fn" type="text" name="fn" ><br><br>
   <label for="ln">Last Name: </label>
   <input id="ln" type="text" name= "ln"><br><br>
   <label for="srn">Student Registration Number: </label>
   <input id="srn" type="text" name= "srn" maxlength="6" placeholder="ex. 'P16***'"><br><br>
   Semester: <select name="semester">
    <optgroup label="1st Year">
     <option>1st Semester</option>
     <option>2nd Semester</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2nd Year">
    <option>3rd Semester</option>
    <option>4th Semester</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="3rd Year">
    <option>5th Semester</option>
    <option>6th Semester</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="4th Year">
    <option>7th Semester</option>
    <option>8th Semester</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select><br><br>
   <input type= "button" value= "Continue" onClick="Check();" >
   <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
   <button onclick="closeWin()">Close Window</button>

   
  </form>
 </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to perform all your checks before you perform the calculation. Right now you ask for input, parse it as floats, do a calculation, then start checking for errors.

Comment: just say document.write no need of mywindow.document

Comment: @Geeky the OP is writing to the opened window's document, not the current one.

Comment: K.Soldas, May I ask why you changed the marked answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My variant with "onfly-validation"

```js
 function closeWin() {
  myWindow.close();
 }

 function trimfield(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
 }

 function Check() {
  var counter = 0;
  var lessonsCount = 0;
  var lesson = []; // same as = new Array()
  lesson[0] = window.prompt("1st Lesson Grade", "0"); // recommended do this in for-loop
  lesson[1] = window.prompt("2nd Lesson Grade", "0");
  lesson[2] = window.prompt("3rd Lesson Grade", "0");
  lesson[3] = window.prompt("4th Lesson Grade", "0");
  lesson[4] = window.prompt("5th Lesson Grade", "0");
  lesson[5] = window.prompt("6th Lesson Grade", "0");
  lessonsCount = lesson.length;
  
  var x = [];
  var sum = 0;
  //* onfly-validation
  for (var j = 0; j < lessonsCount; j++) {
   x[j] = parseFloat(lesson[j]);
   if (isNaN(x[j])) {
    alert("Wrong grade for lesson " + (j + 1));
    return; // got NaN - stop calculation
   } else if (x[j] < 0 || x[j] > 10) {
    alert("Grade for lesson " + (j + 1) + " should be in 0..10");
    return; // wrong number - stop calculation
   } else {
    sum += x[j];
   }
  }
  avrg = sum / lessonsCount; // if you decide add some lessons - you shouldn't fix lessons number in all your code

  var reg = document.getElementById('srn').value;
  var name = document.getElementById('fn').value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById('ln').value;
  var i;
  var hasError = false;
  var myWindow = window.open("", "Grade", "width=500,height=500");
  myWindow.document.write("<h3>The average is: " + avrg + "<br>" + "First Name: " + name + "<br>" + "Last Name: " + lastname + "<br>" + "Studen Registration Number: " + reg + "</h3>");
  /*
  for(i=0; i<6;i++){
   if(!isNaN(lesson[i].value)){
    hasError = true;
    counter=1;
   }
   else if(trimfield(lesson[i].value) == '') {      
    hasError = true;
    lesson[i].focus(); 
    counter=1;
   }
   else if(lesson[i].value<0 || lesson[i].value>10){
    hasError = true;
    counter=1;
   } else
    counter=0;
   }
   
   if(counter==1){
    alert("Wrong Info")
   }  
  return !hasError;
  */
 }
```

```html
<fieldset>
 <legend>Personal Info:</legend>
  <form>
   <label for="fn">First Name:</label>
   <input id="fn" type="text" name="fn" ><br><br>
   <label for="ln">Last Name: </label>
   <input id="ln" type="text" name= "ln"><br><br>
   <label for="srn">Student Registration Number: </label>
   <input id="srn" type="text" name= "srn" maxlength="6" placeholder="ex. 'P16***'"><br><br>
   Semester: <select name="semester">
    <optgroup label="1st Year">
     <option>1st Semester</option>
     <option>2nd Semester</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2nd Year">
    <option>3rd Semester</option>
    <option>4th Semester</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="3rd Year">
    <option>5th Semester</option>
    <option>6th Semester</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="4th Year">
    <option>7th Semester</option>
    <option>8th Semester</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select><br><br>
   <input type= "button" value= "Continue" onClick="Check();" >
   <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
   <button onclick="closeWin()">Close Window</button>

   
  </form>
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: This example continues to the next prompt even when an invalid number/text is entered. They would have to do the entire form again just to correct one answer O_o

Comment: Absolutely, you can run prompts in loop and check values right away

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. My previously posted answer calls the prompts recursively so that a question is validated before continuing to the next.

Comment: Question author said nothing about this behavior. The best solution is show j-prompt until user set correct value, but I added behavior from author's code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work though it needs refactoring. The basic idea is wrap your validation in a function, then while validation function fails keep asking prompt.

```js
function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
function trimfield(str) 
{ 
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); 
}

function Check()
{
  var counter=0;
  var lesson = new Array();
  getNum(0, "1st Lesson Grade");
  getNum(1, "2nd Lesson Grade");
  getNum(2, "3rd Lesson Grade");
  getNum(3, "4th Lesson Grade");
  getNum(4, "5th Lesson Grade");
  getNum(5, "6th Lesson Grade");
  
  x = parseFloat(lesson[0]);
  x1 = parseFloat(lesson[1]);
  x2 = parseFloat(lesson[2]);
  x3 = parseFloat(lesson[3]);
  x4 = parseFloat(lesson[4]);
  x5 = parseFloat(lesson[5]);
  avrg = (x + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)/6;
  var reg = document.getElementById('srn').value;
  var name = document.getElementById('fn').value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById('ln').value;
  var i;
  var myWindow = window.open("", "Grade", "width=500,height=500");
  myWindow.document.write("<h3>The average is: " + avrg  + "<br>" + "First Name: " + name + "<br>"+ "Last Name: " + lastname  + "<br>"+ "Studen Registration Number: " + reg + "</h3>");
  
  function checkNum(n){
      var hasError = false;
      if(isNaN(n)){
        hasError = true;
        counter=1;
      }
      else if(trimfield(n) == '') {      
        hasError = true;
              n.focus(); 
        counter=1;
          }
      else if(n<0 || n>10){
        hasError = true;
        counter=1;
      } else{
        counter=0;
      }
      if(counter==1){
        alert("Wrong Info")
      }

      return !hasError;
  }

  function getNum(index, msg){
    temp = window.prompt(msg, "0");
    if(!checkNum(temp)){
      getNum(index, msg);
    } else{
      lesson[index] = temp;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personal Info:</legend>
    <form>
      <label for="fn">First Name:</label>
      <input id="fn" type="text" name="fn" ><br><br>
      <label for="ln">Last Name: </label>
      <input id="ln" type="text" name= "ln"><br><br>
      <label for="srn">Student Registration Number: </label>
      <input id="srn" type="text" name= "srn" maxlength="6" placeholder="ex. 'P16***'"><br><br>
      Semester: <select name="semester">
        <optgroup label="1st Year">
          <option>1st Semester</option>
          <option>2nd Semester</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="2nd Year">
        <option>3rd Semester</option>
        <option>4th Semester</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="3rd Year">
        <option>5th Semester</option>
        <option>6th Semester</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="4th Year">
        <option>7th Semester</option>
        <option>8th Semester</option>
        </optgroup>
        </select><br><br>
      <input type= "button" value= "Continue" onClick="Check();" >
      <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
      <button onclick="closeWin()">Close Window</button>

      
    </form>
  </fieldset>
```